# Where are the settings in Geary mail client?

Tags: gnome, 16.04, configuration, geary

I just installed Geary (I have used it last year a lot) and I can't seem to find the "settings" button anymore. I swear it was there. Google images shows it too.

Geary looked like this initially when I got it:

[image]

I tried updating from `ppa:geary-team/releases` and it updated but still no settings button visible.

[image]

I searched everywhere and can't seem to find it. Where is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the expected behavior under modern versions of Ubuntu.

According to the [online documentation](http://yorba.org/geary/help/preferences.html) the little 'gear' icon will not be found in the expected place at the right of the toolbar *with current Ubuntu*, using either GNOME shell or Unity:

> The Preferences option is available in *either* Geary's application menu
>   *or* the gear menu in the upper-right of the toolbar. (The location
>   depends on the install desktop shell. For GNOME Shell and Unity, the
>   application menu is available near the top-left corner of the screen.)

So under Unity or GNOME the 'Preferences' menu for Geary can be accessed  with the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> while the 'Accounts' menu can  be accessed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. Both menus are accessible by mouse from the top left corner of the screen. But no 'gear' icon...

The screenshot below illustrates the available access:

[image]

**References:**

- [Using Geary: Preferences](http://yorba.org/geary/help/preferences.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Geary 3.36.1 (Ubuntu 20.04) there is no longer a gear icon, and you can also no longer access it via the context menu of the application. The online help is also no help.

To access the preferences, click the hamburger icon, which opens a menu containing accounts, preferences and keyboard shortcuts. It is a bit hidden, to the right of the search button:

[image]

Sorry that it is in German, here is a translation:

```
Spam leeren...           Empty Spam...
Papierkorb leeren...     Empty Trash...
Konten                   Accounts
Einstellungen            Settings/Preferences
Tastenkombinationen      Keyboard shortcuts
Hilfe                    Help
Info zu Geary            About Geary
```

Answer (score 0):

In Geary 0.12 there is no longer a gear icon. However to access "preferences" etc. click on the envelope icon in the top LEFT corner of the screen.